# node.js file upload typeError Can not read property 'image'

Tags: node.js, file-upload

I am using this program example to upload a image into uploads/fullsize directory. 
The application is running but if I try to upload a image I am getting the following failure:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined at Object.handle
>   (/Users/machupicchu/Desktop/test/app.js:46:23) at next_layer
>   (/Users/machupicchu/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:103:13)
>   at Route.dispatch
>   (/Users/machupicchu/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:107:5)
>   at c
>   (/Users/machupicchu/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:195:24)
>   at Function.proto.process_params
>   (/Users/machupicchu/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:251:12)
>   at next
>   (/Users/machupicchu/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:189:19)
>   at next
>   (/Users/machupicchu/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:38)
>   at next
>   (/Users/machupicchu/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:166:38)
>   at Layer.staticMiddleware [as handle]
>   (/Users/machupicchu/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/node_modules/serve-static/index.js:55:61)
>   at trim_prefix
>   (/Users/machupicchu/Desktop/test/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:226:17)

The application looks like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var path = require ('path');
var port = 3000;
var fs = require('fs');


//var collection;
//dataExt = require('./routes/serverExtend');
// setup middleware
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public')); //setup static public directory

app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); //optional since express defaults to CWD/views
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// Start server
app.listen(port);
console.log('App started on port ' + port);


var form = "<!DOCTYPE HTML><html><body>" +
"<form method='post' action='/upload' enctype='multipart/form-data'>" +
"<input type='file' name='image'/>" +
"<input type='submit' /></form>" +
"</body></html>";

app.get('/', function (req, res){
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html' });
    res.end(form);  
});

app.get('/uploads/fullsize/:file', function (req, res){
    file = req.params.file;
    var img = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + "/uploads/fullsize/" + file);
    res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/jpg' });
    res.end(img, 'binary');

});

/// Post files
app.post('/upload', function(req, res) {

    fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function (err, data) {

        var imageName = req.files.image.name

        /// If there's an error
        if(!imageName){

            console.log("There was an error")
            res.redirect("/");
            res.end();

        } else {

          var newPath = __dirname + "/uploads/fullsize/" + imageName;

          /// write file to uploads/fullsize folder
          fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {

            /// let's see it
            res.redirect("/uploads/fullsize/" + imageName);

          });
        }
    });
});
```

Can someone help me why I am getting the TypeError??
Also created my directory where the files should be save. 
app.js
uploads -> fullsize -> images.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need multipart middleware for your file upload to work as `body-parser` does not provide it.

First, add this to the top of your app:

```
var multipart = require('connect-multiparty');
```

Next, edit your post route slightly:

```
app.post('/upload', multipart(), function(req, res) {
   // ... 
}
```

Now `req.files` should now be avaiable to you in your `POST /upload` route.