# Upload image to Node.js image' of undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, file-upload

Sorry for poor Indent
I'm new to node.js ,trying to upload image to node.js
check lot's of answer , please coorect me if I'm wrong

1.bodyParser need a middleware to handle binary file, such as IMAGE
if I don't use it, it will show

> `undefine token`

2.use Multer as a  middleware , like this

> ```
> var multer = require('multer') 
>
> var upload = multer({ dest:'/Node/file-upload/uploads/' });
>
> app.post('/upload',upload.array(),songs.upload);
> ```

3. follow [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer#readme) , req.files is the image file , req.body is the file name
   so I use fs.readFile to read the file

> ```
> fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function (err, data)
> ```

4.than I need a file path and file name , I use req.body

> ```
> var dirname = "/Node/file-upload/uploads/";
>
> var newPath = dirname + req.body.image.filename;
> ```

5.than writ the data into the destination by this

> ```
> fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err)
> ```

I'm not sure what part I missed , it took me 10 hours to do this please help

it always tell me TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined

app.js

```
var    express = require('express')
      ,bodyParser = require('body-parser')
      ,app = express()
      ,multer  =  require('multer')
      ,binary = require('binary')
      ,fs = require('fs')
      ,util= require('util')
      ,http = require('http')
      ,multer = require('multer')
      ,upload = multer({ dest: '/Node/file-upload/uploads/' });

 app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // support encoded bodies.
 app.use(bodyParser.json({limit: '5mb'}));


songs = require('./routes/route');

app.listen(3000, function () {
      console.log('Example app listening on port 3000!');
                          });
app.post('/upload',upload.array(),songs.upload);
```

route.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uri = "mongodb://xxxxxx:xxxxxxx@ds061365.mongolab.com:61365/aweitest";
mongoose.connect(uri);
// we're connected!
var db = mongoose.connection.db;
var BSON = require('bson').BSONPure;
var binary = require('binary');
var body = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection errrrrrrrror:'));

db.once('open', function() {
     console.log("mongodb is connected!!");
 });

exports.upload = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
       fs.readFile(req.files.image.path, function (err, data){
            var dirname = "/Node/file-upload/uploads/";
            var newPath = dirname + req.body.image.filename;
       fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
            if(err){
                res.json({'response':"Error"});
            }else {
                res.json({'response':"Saved"});
          }
       });
    });
  };
```

error

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of undefined
at exports.upload (c:\Users\awei\WebstormProjects\untitled\routes\girlshanlder.js:92:26)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
at multerMiddleware (c:\node_modules\multer\lib\make-middleware.js:18:41)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at next (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:131:13)
at Route.dispatch (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:277:22
at Function.process_params (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
at next (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:271:10)
at jsonParser (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\body-parser\lib\types\json.js:107:37)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:312:13)
at c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:7
at Function.process_params (c:\Users\awei\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:330:12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`upload.array()` in your `app.js` should be

```
upload.array('image',1) // 1 here is number of files you would upload
```

the in your `songs.upload` middleware you would get req.files.image as an array,

So you would better check for the length of the array and iterate over it to save each file, or if you just want to save 1 file you can do following.

Example:

app.js

```
app.post('/upload',upload.array('image',1),songs.upload);
```

route.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var uri = "mongodb://xxxxxx:xxxxxxx@ds061365.mongolab.com:61365/aweitest";
mongoose.connect(uri);
// we're connected!
var db = mongoose.connection.db;
var BSON = require('bson').BSONPure;
var binary = require('binary');
var body = require('body-parser');
var fs = require('fs');

db.on('error', console.error.bind(console, 'connection errrrrrrrror:'));

db.once('open', function() {
     console.log("mongodb is connected!!");
 });

exports.upload = function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body);
       fs.readFile(req.files.image[0].path, function (err, data){
            var dirname = "/Node/file-upload/uploads/";
            var newPath = dirname + req.body.image.filename;
       fs.writeFile(newPath, data, function (err) {
            if(err){
                res.json({'response':"Error"});
            }else {
                res.json({'response':"Saved"});
          }
       });
    });
  };
```

Comment: Thanks for reply , I change 'app.post('/upload',upload.array(),songs.upload);'
still reply  'Cannot read property 'image' of undefined'
at
'fs.readFile(req.files.image[0].path, function (err, data)'

Comment: `upload.array('image',1)`

Comment: btw I use POSTMAN to test this api

Comment: I check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25461888/node-js-file-upload-typeerror-can-not-read-property-image

it define the file as <input type='file' name='image'/> 
and I use postman I check the header is Content-Type →
Content-Type
The mime type of this content
text/html; charset=utf-8
not sure what's wrong...

Comment: I think it's a content-type issue , I will try as soon as this problem fix http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35630837/postman-can-not-change-content-type

Comment: you are right about the answer , I use wrong tool option to test the api , I use POSTMAN , i should chose "form-data" and assing a key have to same as .array('image',1) "image" thank you ;DDDD

Comment: i dont know how do you send multipart data using postman, but you give a try with some html form

Comment: in postman , there is an option "form-data" , have to assign the key value , than it works:)